# How to import BeamSearchDecoder after tensorflow update?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

```
from tensorflow.contrib.seq2seq import BeamSearchDecoder as beam_search_decoder
```

gives

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

The latest versions of Tensorflow  do not contain `contrib`, so how can I use the function?

Answer (score -1):

[BeamSearchDecoder](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/seq2seq/BeamSearchDecoder) is now part of [Tensorflow Addons](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons), which should be installed separately via `pip`:

```
pip install tensorflow-addons
```

After that, you can use it either as you try here:

```
from tensorflow_addons.seq2seq import BeamSearchDecoder as beam_search_decoder
```

or directly as suggested in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/seq2seq/BeamSearchDecoder) and the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/networks_seq2seq_nmt#use_tf-addons_beamsearchdecoder):

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
tfa.seq2seq.BeamSearchDecoder(...)
```